# access to plist in app bundle returns null

Tags: objective-c, ios, plist, nsbundle

I'm using a piece of code I've used before with success to load a plist into an array:

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"species_names" ofType:@"plist"];
NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
```

The initWithContentsOf File is failing (array is null, suggesting it can't find the plist in the app bundle).

Under the iPhone simulator I've checked that the path created by the first line points to the app file (it does), and used the Finder context menu "Show package contants" to prove to myself that "species_name.plist" is actually in the bundle--with a length that suggests it contains stuff, so it *should* work (and has in other iOS apps I've written).  Suggestions most welcome...

[env Xcode 4.2 beta, iOS 4.3.2].

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You should use `initWithContentsOfFile:` method of `NSDictionary` instance, not `NSArray`.
Here is sample:

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"species_names" ofType:@"plist"];
NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithArray:[dict objectForKey:@"Root"]];
```

Or this:

```
NSString *errorDesc = nil;
NSPropertyListFormat format;
NSString    *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"startups" ofType:@"plist"];
NSData      *plistXML = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsAtPath:path];
NSDictionary *temp = (NSDictionary *)[NSPropertyListSerialization                     
                                          propertyListFromData:plistXML
mutabilityOption:NSPropertyListMutableContainersAndLeaves
                                          format:&format
                                          errorDescription:&errorDesc];
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithArray:[temp objectForKey:@"Root"]];
```

**EDIT**
You can use `initWithContentsOfFile:` method of `NSArray` with file created with `writeToFile:atomically:` method of `NSArray`. Plist created with  `writeToFile:atomically:` has this stucture:

```
<plist version="1.0">
<array>
    ...Content...
</array>
</plist>
```

And Plist created in XCode has this stucture:

```
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    ...Content...
</dict>
</plist>
```

Thats why `initWithContentsOfFile:` method of `NSArray` dosnt work.

Answer (score 3):

`plist` of this type:

[image]

OR (basically both are same)

[image]

Can be read like this:

```
NSString *file = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"appFeatures" ofType:@"plist"];
NSArray *_arrFeats = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:file];
NSLog(@"%d", _arrFeats.count);
```

Where `appFeatures` is name of the `plist`.
(iOS 6.1)

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple metod:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self plistData];
}


- (void)plistData
{
    NSString *file = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"appFeatures" ofType:@"plist"];
    NSArray *messages = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:file];
    NSLog(@"%d", messages.count);

    for (int i=0; i<messages.count; i++)
    {
        NSString *data = [messages objectAtIndex:i];
        NSLog(@"\n Data = %@",data);
    }
}
```